# Using st_crs to apply a crs to my data is coming up with "Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-")"

Tags: r, mapping, r-sf

I'm trying to apply a co-ordinate reference system to a dataset I'm using but am unable to do so. I'm not very experienced with this following only a few tutorials, so it's possible it's a really simple fix. My error is "Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-") :
no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')""

The full dataset is below and should run in any R as I'm pulling the dataset from online, thanks :) I'm hoping to use plot(wildlife) to see the dataset after applying the crs.

```
library(tidyverse) #lots
library(dplyr) #pipes
library(ggplot2)#plots
library(sf) #maps
wildlife <- st_read("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/07c7d3a8031b401d80feb16512a659d5_13.geojson") #pulling geojson data from online.
wildlife <- tibble(wildlife)
glimpse(wildlife)

wildlife <- wildlife %>% 
select(site_no, geometry)

st_crs(wildlife) <- 4326 #this line results in an error
st_crs(wildlife)
```

Comment: Your issue is probably that you converted to a tibble. If you don't convert to a tibble it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it's somewhat hard to interpret exactly what you are asking when you say: `"the full dataset is below and should run in any R as I'm pulling the dataset from online, thanks :). "`

If you are asking whether this dataset is somehow damaged and cannot be plotted, then I can say, no.  This dataset reads and plots without issue.  It's hard to guess what is wrong with your code or guess your intended goals, but the code for simply reading the file and plotting the data follows:

Get Data:

```
wildlife <- st_read("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/07c7d3a8031b401d80feb16512a659d5_13.geojson")
```

Explore Data:

```
glimpse(wildlife)                    # dim 254 x 8
head(wildlife, 3)
```

Plot Data:

```
plot(wildlife$geometry)
```

If you wanted to apply this feature to this data, the following code works without error:

```
st_crs(wildlife) <- 4326
```

The plotted data can be view from this link.[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPbs.png)

Comment: Ah apparently tibbling it was the issue, good to know it wasn't the data though thanks :)